# Interval Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory, an interval graph is an undirected graph formed from a set of intervals on the real line, with a vertex for each interval and an edge between vertices whose intervals intersect. It is the intersection graph of the intervals.  Is it possible that the join of two intervals graphs is an interval graph?

In addition,

By definition of an Interval graph. Is it possible that the CORONA of two interval graphs is an interval. And also for the COMPOSITION of two interval graphs is also an interval. I was trying to find a result about it but I can't find one. I am hoping for your response. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this only happens in the case where all the intervals overlap, giving a complete graph both for the two original graphs and the join.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am finding results but I can't find any.

Comment: By definition of an Interval graph. Is it possible that the CORONA of two interval graphs is an interval. And also for the COMPOSITION of two interval graphs is also an interval. I was trying to find a result about it but I can't find one. I am hoping for your response. Thank you very much.

Comment: By definition of an Interval graph. Is it possible that the CORONA of two interval graphs is an interval. And also for the COMPOSITION of two interval graphs is also an interval. I was trying to find a result about it but I can't find one. I am hoping for your response. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should add definitions of the Corona and composition of graphs - these are (in my experience) not as commonly encountered as graph joins.

Comment: What have you tried? Given two interval graphs $G$ and $H$, you should be able to find that the corona product of $G$ and $H$ is an interval graph if and only if $G$ is a path graph ($G$ the graph not duplicated) or $H$ is an empty graph (hint: show that if $G$ is not a path, one interval must be fully covered). and, using the result on join, the composition of $G$ and $H$ is an interval graph if and only if $G$ is the empty graph or $H$ is a complete graph (hint: the composition product contains several join products of $H$ with itself as induced subgraphs).

Comment: To caduk: Do you have a reference where I can find such result? Can you give me example for that?

Comment: I have no references, these results are not very hard to prove. You should try to prove them yourself, this will be more beneficial for you. Use the hints I gave and you should manage to prove them. If you struggle to much, I can write down a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @caduk Thank you for giving me the hints. I've struggling much. Would you mind giving me a detailed explanation? Thank you

Comment: @caduk Thank you very much  for your ideas. I appreciated much your kindness response. I already tried to prove your 2nd statement. However, I just want to clarify if this empty graph that you are pertaining is the graph that has vertex/vertices only and has no edges? If so then your statement make sense provided the interval assigned to each vertex of G and H doesn't need to be preserve as we take their composition product. But is it okay if intervals assigned in each vertex of G and H respectively will not be preserve in their composition? I hope you can help me out with this. Thank you.

Comment: I mean a graph with no edges. What do you mean by preserved in their composition ?

Comment: @caduk? I hope you have the answer. You're help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @caduk For example for a graph G which is empty with 2 vertices: v1 and v2 then let say the associated intervals are v1=[0, 1] and v2=[2, 3] On the other hand, for graph H which is compelete for example H=:K_3 with vertices u1, u2 and u3. Then let say the associated intervals are u1=[5, 6], u2=[6, 7] and u3=[6, 8]. Then my question is, does the given intervals that we assigned for each vertex of G and H will be preserve if we now take their composition product?

Comment: In the composition graph, each vertex correspond to both a vertex of $G$ and a vertex of $H$, which one would you keep? When asking if the composition graph is an interval graph, we are allowed to define the intervals we want, as long as it is coherent with the structure of the graph. I will write down the proofs I have.

Comment: @caduk I see so the intervals assigned in G and H doesn't need to be preserve upon taking their composition.. Thank you very much for this Prof. Caduk. I really appreciate your efforts. God bless you..

Comment: @caduk Good day Prof. Caduk, Hope you are doing good. I just want to clarify again about the empty graph that you are pertaining. I already asked you last time about this and you said that the empty graph is the graph that has no edge/edges right? Meaning it has vertex/vertices only? But base on your proof about corona of two interval graph you have an assumption that if H is not empty then H has at least one vertex. So what is the empty graph here? Because some author varied on defining empty graph. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Good day Prof. Caduk, Hope you are doing good. I just want to clarify again about the empty graph that you are pertaining. I already asked you last time about this and you said that the empty graph is the graph that has no edge/edges right? Meaning it has vertex/vertices only? But base on your proof about corona of two interval graph you have an assumption that if H is not empty then H has at least one vertex. So what is the empty graph here? Because some author varied on defining empty graph. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

**graph join:**
Let $G$ and $H$ be two interval graphs. Let's show that the join of $G\nabla H$ is an interval graph if and only if one of the two graphs $G$ and $H$ is a complete graph.

Suppose one of the graphs is not a complete graph. Let $u,v$ be a pair of vertices that is not an edge. Because the graph is chordal, it is easy to see that the other graph is the complete graph (otherwise, a missing edge in the other graph would induce $C_4$).
Another way to see it with the intuition of intervals: If an edge is missing in $G$, this implies that there exist two disjoint intervals.
By the definition of a graph join, every interval of $H$ must intersect every interval of $G$, and so must cover the gap between the two disjoint intervals. So all intervals of $H$ intersect each other, hence $H$ is a complete graph.

Every join between a complete graph $G$ and an interval graph $H$ is still an interval graph: Take a set of intervals $S$ describing $H$. We can describe $G$ by a set of intervals that covers every interval in $S$. The union of both sets of intervals describes the $G\nabla H$.

**Edit:** proofs for Corona product and composition of graphs.

**Corona product:**
Let $G$ and $H$ be two interval graphs such that the corona product $G\odot H$ is an interval graph. Lets show that $G$ must be a path graph, or $H$ must be empty.
Suppose $G$ is not a path  graph. Two cases: $G$ have a vertex of degree $3$, of $G$ have a cycle (which must be of length 3). In both cases, it implies that some interval (associated with a vertex $v$) is fully covered by the other intervals. If $H$ is non-empty ($H$ have at least one vertex), then vertices corresponding to the copy of $H$ linked to $v$ must also be linked to the intervals covering $v$, which is a contradiction. So $H$ must be empty.

If $H$ is empty, then the corona product is simply $G$, so it is an interval graph.
If $G$ is a path graph, then we choose the corresponding intervals such that each interval contains an interval covered only by itself. We can place in this region a set of interval describing the graph $H$. The set of intervals obtained described the corona product of $G$ and $H$, so it is an interval graph.

**graph composition:**
Let $G$ and $H$ be two interval graphs such that the graph composition $G[H]$ is an interval graph. Lets show that $H$ must be a complete graph or $G$ must have no edges.

Suppose $G$ have at least one edge. Then the vertices associated with the two extremities of this edge induce a join the graph $H\nabla H$. Has seen before, this implies that $H$ must be a complete graph.

If $G$ has no edges, $G[H]$ is made of disjoint copies of $H$, so it is an interval graph.
If $H$ is a complete graph on $n$ vertices, then we can verify that taking $n$ exact same set of intervals describing $G$ gives a description of $G[H]$

Comment: Thank you for this explaination. I was finding results about my question but I can't find any.

Comment: Why downvotes? is it possible to point out an error in my proof, or at least have constructive feedback?

Comment: I don't know why it's downvotes. I click the upvotes.

Comment: By definition of an Interval graph. Is it possible that the CORONA of two interval graphs is an interval. And also for the COMPOSITION of two interval graphs is also an interval. I was trying to find a result about it but I can't find one. I am hoping for your response. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EuniceSolijon I updated my answer with proofs for the corona product and the composition of graphs.

Comment: I see so the intervals assigned in G and H doesn't need to be preserve upon taking their composition.. Thank you very much for this Prof. Caduk. I really appreciate your efforts. God bless you..

Comment: Good day Prof. Caduk,

Hope you are doing good. I just want to clarify again about  the empty graph that you are pertaining. I already asked you last time about this and you said that the empty graph is the graph that has no edge/edges right? Meaning it has vertex/vertices only? But base on your proof about corona of two interval graph you have an assumption that if H is not empty then H has at least one vertex. So what is the empty graph here?  Because some author varied on defining empty graph. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Good day Prof. Caduk, Hope you are doing good. I just want to clarify again about the empty graph that you are pertaining. I already asked you last time about this and you said that the empty graph is the graph that has no edge/edges right? Meaning it has vertex/vertices only? But base on your proof about corona of two interval graph you have an assumption that if H is not empty then H has at least one vertex. So what is the empty graph here? Because some author varied on defining empty graph. Thank you for the response.